# Determine a,b,c of quadratic equation using data points

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to determine a,b,c value of `y=ax2+bx+c` using the set of data point which varies upto 100 points.For Ex (-270,69) (-269,90) (-280,50). I have used [Using points to generate quadratic equation to interpolate data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896577/using-points-to-generate-quadratic-equation-to-interpolate-data) url for determine the a,b,c value.but I found the difference between a,b,c value in both method. 
Note: I can not use Numpy into production code.

```
def coefficent(x,y):
    x_1 = x[0]
    x_2 = x[1]
    x_3 = x[2]
    y_1 = y[0]
    y_2 = y[1]
    y_3 = y[2]

    a = y_1/((x_1-x_2)*(x_1-x_3)) + y_2/((x_2-x_1)*(x_2-x_3)) + y_3/((x_3-x_1)*(x_3-x_2))

    b = -y_1*(x_2+x_3)/((x_1-x_2)*(x_1-x_3))
    -y_2*(x_1+x_3)/((x_2-x_1)*(x_2-x_3))
    -y_3*(x_1+x_2)/((x_3-x_1)*(x_3-x_2))

    c = y_1*x_2*x_3/((x_1-x_2)*(x_1-x_3))
    + y_2*x_1*x_3/((x_2-x_1)*(x_2-x_3))
    + y_3*x_1*x_2/((x_3-x_1)*(x_3-x_2))

    return a,b,c

x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,7,12]

a,b,c = coefficent(x, y)
print a,b,c


> import numpy as np
>>> A, B, C = np.polyfit([1,2,3],[4,7,12],2)
>>> print A, B, C
1.0 -4.2727620148e-15 3.0
>>> print A, 'x^2 +', B, 'x +', C
1.0 x^2 + -4.2727620148e-15 x + 3.0
>>>
```

Comment: So, you don't have access to numpy, am I right? Then why not to just copypaste the formulas form answer you are quoting. They are as good in python as in any other language...

Comment: I took from one of the post

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Can you use numpy or not? If not, copypaste code presented in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896577/using-points-to-generate-quadratic-equation-to-interpolate-data. If yes, just use it (see docs: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)

Comment: I have modified question.I have tried this and find the difference between two method. could not understand why it is

Comment: So, what's the output of print a,b,c?

Comment: Be sure to avoid integer division by the way, that is probably the issue. Try x = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0] and y = [4.0, 7.0, 12.0]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you split the lines calculating `b` and `c` before posting on SO?  The code as pasted in the question won't compile.  This version does:

```
def coefficient(x,y):
    x_1 = x[0]
    x_2 = x[1]
    x_3 = x[2]
    y_1 = y[0]
    y_2 = y[1]
    y_3 = y[2]

    a = y_1/((x_1-x_2)*(x_1-x_3)) + y_2/((x_2-x_1)*(x_2-x_3)) + y_3/((x_3-x_1)*(x_3-x_2))

    b = (-y_1*(x_2+x_3)/((x_1-x_2)*(x_1-x_3))
         -y_2*(x_1+x_3)/((x_2-x_1)*(x_2-x_3))
         -y_3*(x_1+x_2)/((x_3-x_1)*(x_3-x_2)))

    c = (y_1*x_2*x_3/((x_1-x_2)*(x_1-x_3))
        +y_2*x_1*x_3/((x_2-x_1)*(x_2-x_3))
        +y_3*x_1*x_2/((x_3-x_1)*(x_3-x_2)))

    return a,b,c

x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,7,12]

a,b,c = coefficient(x, y)

print "a = ", a
print "b = ", b
print "c = ", c
```

The output is impeccable:

```
a =  1
b =  0
c =  3
```

This is more accurate (by 4*10<sup>-15</sup> or so in the coefficient of `b`) than the answer from `numpy`.  It is also mathematically accurate for the three data points.

What is the problem with the answer that your code is giving you?